# problem Automatic addition of "http" in redirect route laravel 7.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

"http://" is added to the beginning of the url when I want to redirect route

for example 
true redirect => site.com/publisher/dashboard
But something happens => site.com/http://publisher/dashboard

Contolletr.php :

```
return redirect()->route('publisher.dashboard');
```

web.php:

```
Route::namespace('Publisher')->prefix('publisher')->name('publisher.')->group(function () {

Route::middleware(['publisher','checkStatus:publisher'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'PublisherController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
})
```

Comment: What happens if you use this: ```return redirect()->route('dashboard');```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but maybe try changing
Route::get('dashboard', 'PublisherController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');

To:
Route::get('/dashboard/', 'PublisherController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');

Comment: No . Does not work